# How to get id from the task in which I click

Tags: php, laravel

So I have "tasks", and each task can have multiple notes.
I display tasks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Id</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Task title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Created by</th>
            <th>Created on</th>
            @if (Auth::user()->role=='admin')
            <th>Admin</th>
            @endif
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        @foreach ($task as $task)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$task->task_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->project->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->task_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->task_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->status}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->priority}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->created_at}}</td>

            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>   
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('tasks.notes',$task)}}">Notes</a>
```

Each task is a row and as you can see at the end there is a button which gets the user to the notes view.
I need to get the task_id from the task you click on, so I can assign that task_id to the note, this way every task has its own notes.
This are my relations between "Task" and "Note";
Task model:

```
public function notes(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Note','task_id');
    }
```

Note model:

```
public function task(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task','task_id');
    }
```

And this is where I display the notes:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Note</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            @foreach($notes->where('task_id',$task->task_id) as $note)
            <tr>
                <td>Created by {{$note->user}}<td>
                <td>{{$note->note}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

My NoteController index function:

```
public function index(Task $task)
    {


        $task_id = $task['task_id'];

        return view('notes.index', [
            'notes' => Note::all(),
            'user' => User::all(),
            'task' => $task_id, 

        ]);


    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see where you're defining the `tasks.notes` route.

Comment: Side note: `@foreach ($task as $task)` you shouldn't use the same variable name for your array (or `Collection` in this case) and each iteration. Consider using pluralized name, such as `@foreach ($tasks as $task)`. I've seen this cause issues before.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki This is the route ```Route::get('/tasks/{task}/notes', ['as' => 'tasks.notes', 'uses' => 'NoteController@index']);```

Answer (score 1):

Send the `id` instead of the whole object in the blade like :

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('tasks.notes', $task->id)}}">Notes</a>
```

Then in the `index` action receive it and get the related task notes like :

```
public function index($task_id)
{
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    return view('notes.index', [
        'notes' => Note::all(),
        'user' => $task->notes,
        'task' => $task,
    ]);
}
```

In the notes blade, you've just to loop through them :

```
@foreach($notes as $note)
```

Comment: This worked. My problem now is that when I submit a note it doesnt pass any task id to index so it gives me an error